# Determining Orbital Velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gravity, newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion, velocity

Is there any way to determine the orbital velocity of a point around another stationary point, if I don't know the mass of either of the points but know the force that gravity exerts and the distance between them.
I'd like to know at what velocity I should push the non-stationary point perpendicular to the stationary point, so that it will maintain a circular orbit.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds and looks like a school problem.
If the orbit is circular, write the expression of the acceleration (normal component only, assume v=cte).
a=V^2/R
Then use Newton's 2nd law: f=m*a and ....work out the answer

Comment: The masses are unknown in the OP's problem. There is probably not enough information.

Comment: I ended up just giving my points a mass. And solving the problem using Kepler's Laws.